# What is the best way to store data from Modbus TCP?

Tags: plc

What is the best way to store all data generated from Modbus TCP in SCADA? it is better to store it in a file or directly to SQL Server?

is data stored every second?

If it store in SQL Server every second doesn't the database become very huge?

Please help, thanks

Comment: The best way to store it is to carve the binary into rock with hieroglyphs, since that storage medium doesn't rely on technology to work and will stand the test of time with very low data retention. Seriously, define "best". Also, if the question isn't about PLC programming specifically, I don't think it is on-topic here.

Comment: Very funny, I dont see any stone in every PLC. Please dont reply if it is not helping bro

Comment: Asking for the best something is really asking for opinions, which is off-topic. Also I don't see how this is an electrical engineering question either.

Comment: i accept any opinion anybody given, if its not clear, just point it out, i will explain. I look for related tag i can find, this the closest one. I can see it is related, because i get data from plc. Thanks for your positive answer @Justme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'database' is a collection of data whether it is in a so called 'flat file' or whether it is a relational database like Microsoft's SQL server and anything in between. Disk storage is finite, so at some point the disk will fill.
Then you need to consider how the data will be used. Putting it in a relational database may offer some advantage in terms of time stamping the data and being able to query based on time, value etc. A flat file will need some post processing to be able to do that.
There is no general 'best' - you have solutions and constraints. These need to be weighed up against what you want to achieve.

Generally, for a SCADA system, you have the data (or 'process value/variable'), a tag to identify the data and a timestamp.
The path of least resistance is to use a database server of some type that will timestamp the data for you and manage the storage. The price you pay is it might not be the most size efficient method. For managing historical data you might employ techniques like 'sharding' and compression to negate this.